# Search an element of Vector from specific index in c++

Tags: c++

```
vector<int>v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(5);
int pos = find(v.begin(),v.end(),4)-v.begin();

Answer : pos = 3
```

find() will search from beginning to end and return index.
is there any way to search from a specific index like i want to search from index 2 to 4 in the vector.

Comment: Use `v.begin()+2` and `v.begin()+4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use addition operations.

```
vector<int>v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(5);
int pos = find(v.begin()+2,v.begin()+4, 4)-(v.begin()+2);

Answer : pos = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `std::find` and `std::distance` gives you the index:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int>v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto pos = distance(v.begin(), find(v.begin() + 2, v.end() + 4, 4));
    cout << pos;
}

Output: 
3
```